# How to convert a string of numbers with miscellaneous number of spaces to a series of Int variables in Java.

Tags: java, string

So I will be given three numbers separated by an unknown number of spaces from an input box on a JOptionPane (the spaces could vary between number as well so five between the first and second and then maybe 8 between the second and third) What I need to is then take these numbers and use each of them as a variable in the rest of my code. I am having trouble assigning these numbers once in the string to the three variables. What I was trying to do was use trim() to get rid of all spaces then just parse the charAt() for position 0,1, and 2 into each variable separately. I get an error everytime that reads:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Radix 56 greater than Character.MAX_RADIX at java.lan.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source).

NOTE:
I have stopped at the first parse because it isn't working I would proceed to parse the other two but no sense going on when this first does not function right.

The code I am using for this bit is:

```
String values = "0";
int numLinks = 0;
int start = 0;
int numPass = 0;

values = JOptionPaine.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Values: ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
values.trim();
numLinks = Integer.parseInt(values, values.char.At(0));
System.out.print(numLinks);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `parseInt` fails is that the second parameter that you pass is interpreted as the radix (the numeric base for reading the number), which is certainly *not* what you are looking to achieve.

When you have a string that has multiple numbers separated by variable number of whitespace characters, you can use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) to do the reading:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(values);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(sc.nextInteger());
}
```

At this point, `List<Integer>` contains the numbers from the input string, converted to `Integer` type.

Comment: Could I instead place them into an array as opposed to an Array list? just increment in the index every time I add a value and then do it that way?

Comment: @bobHarding You can convert a list to an array. The problem with an array, though, is that you need to know the size at the time you create it. List, on the other hand, lets you add elements as you go.

Comment: Valid!, though I will only be receiving 3 numbers a time from the user so I could use an array. I ended up just scanning 3 times because like I said I know I will only be given three inputs from the user.

Comment: @bobHarding I am glad that it worked for you. If you are no longer looking for an improved answer to your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that the problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `parseInt` wrong. Its signature is

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

You are passing as the second argument a character which gets promoted to an int, its encoding value is then used as the radix, which is wrong. Just forget the second argument (I'm assuming you are working in base 10).

In addition `.trim()` just removes leading and trailing white space. To remove whitespace between numbers you should use

```
String[] tokens = values.split("\\s+")
```

Which splits the string into tokens separated by the regular expression specified (which is "one or more whitespace characters").